# img-circle class becomes oval in shape after using customized css in bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I am new to bootstrap, and I have to make an image circle in shape using bootstrap. When I add my own CSS for this image, it becomes an oval in shape. Following is the html and css for this.

CSS:

```
.person {
            border: 10px solid transparent;
            margin-bottom: 25px;
            width: 80%;
            height: 80%;
            opacity: 0.7;
        }
        .person:hover {
            border-color: #f1f1f1;
        }
```

HTML:

```
<div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-4">
                <p>
                    <strong>Test Member 1</strong>
                </p>
                <br />
                <a href="#demo" data-toggle="collapse">
                    <img src="images/bandmember.jpg" class="img-circle person" alt="Band Manager" />
                </a>
                <div id="demo" class="collapse">
                    <p>Guitarist and Lead Vocalist</p>
                    <p>Loves long walks on the beach</p>
                    <p>Member since 1988</p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-4">
                <p><strong>Test Member 2</strong></p><br />
                <a href="#demo2" data-toggle="collapse">
                    <img src="images/bandmember.jpg" class="img-circle person" alt="Random Name">
                </a>
                <div id="demo2" class="collapse">
                    <p>Guitarist and Lead Vocalist</p>
                    <p>Loves long walks on the beach</p>
                    <p>Member since 1988</p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-4">
                <p><strong>Test Member 3</strong></p><br />
                <a href="#demo3" data-toggle="collapse">
                    <img src="images/bandmember.jpg" class="img-circle person" alt="Random Name">
                </a>
                <div id="demo3" class="collapse">
                    <p>Guitarist and Lead Vocalist</p>
                    <p>Loves long walks on the beach</p>
                    <p>Member since 1988</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: Not sure what your issue is exactly. You have stated exactly what's causing the oval shape - your own CSS so... remove it?

Comment: I have to use that css too.

Comment: It's your percentage based width/height. Put your image in a container with an overflow:hidden. Then set the height/width on the container, not the image. You should be able to just specify either the height or width and set the opposite to auto. E.G. Width:80% & height:auto;

Answer (score 1):

These styles:

```
width: 80%;
height: 80%;
```

...don't set the width/height as relative to the current size. Rather, they set the width/height relative to the containing block. Thus, you're almost guaranteed to have the width and height not match.

You will need to use different sizing units other than %.

Comment: I used 50x50 but the issue is same

Comment: Perhaps there's a min/max width/height style that's affecting you. I'd use the DOM/style inspector in your browser developer tools to see which styles are being applied to the images.

Comment: Thanks the issue is resolved after removing width and height from my CSS.

Answer (score 0):

Hi please check this solution it might be help you.

```html
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <style type="text/css">
        .person
        {
            border: 10px solid transparent;
            height: 200px;
            width: 200px;
            padding: 10px;
            opacity: 0.7;
        }
        .person:hover
        {
            border-color: #f1f1f1;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-4">
            <p>
                <strong>Test Member 1</strong>
            </p>
            <br />
            <a href="#demo" data-toggle="collapse">
                <img src="images/bandmember.jpg" class="img-responsive img-circle person" alt="Random Name">
            </a>
            <div id="demo" class="collapse">
                <p>
                    Guitarist and Lead Vocalist</p>
                <p>
                    Loves long walks on the beach</p>
                <p>
                    Member since 1988</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-4">
            <p>
                <strong>Test Member 2</strong></p>
            <br />
            <a href="#demo2" data-toggle="collapse">
                <img src="images/bandmember.jpg" class="img-responsive img-circle person" alt="Random Name">
            </a>
            <div id="demo2" class="collapse">
                <p>
                    Guitarist and Lead Vocalist</p>
                <p>
                    Loves long walks on the beach</p>
                <p>
                    Member since 1988</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-4">
            <p>
                <strong>Test Member 3</strong></p>
            <br />
            <a href="#demo3" data-toggle="collapse">
                <img src="images/bandmember.jpg" class="img-responsive img-circle person" alt="Random Name">
            </a>
            <div id="demo3" class="collapse">
                <p>
                    Guitarist and Lead Vocalist</p>
                <p>
                    Loves long walks on the beach</p>
                <p>
                    Member since 1988</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```